In Xcode I can't find BaseConfiguration settings in BuildSettings for my macos app
I have been trying to get a macos app to build in xcode but keep getting this output for pod install and a subsequent black screen if I run the project.
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Pod installation complete! There are 7 dependencies from the Podfile and 16 total pods installed.

[!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `Runner` to `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig` or include the `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig` in your build configuration (`Runner/Configs/AppInfo.xcconfig`).

[!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `Runner` to `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.release.xcconfig` or include the `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.release.xcconfig` in your build configuration (`Runner/Configs/AppInfo.xcconfig`).

[!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `Runner` to `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig` or include the `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig` in your build configuration (`Runner/Configs/AppInfo.xcconfig`).
Pods cleaned and reinstalled successfully.

I have set Runner/Configs/Release similar to this:
#include "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.release.xcconfig"
#include "../../Flutter/Flutter-Release.xcconfig"
#include "Warnings.xcconfig"

and I have a Podfile like this:
platform :osx, '10.14'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', 'Debug' => :debug, 'Profile' => :release, 'Release' => :release

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'ephemeral', 'Flutter-Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure \"flutter pub get\" is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Flutter-Generated.xcconfig, then run \"flutter pub get\""
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_macos_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_macos_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '10.14'
      config.build_settings['FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS'] ||= '$(inherited)'
      config.build_settings['FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS'] << ' $(PROJECT_DIR)/Flutter/ephemeral'
    end
  end

  # Add base configuration references
  project = Xcodeproj::Project.open('Runner.xcodeproj')
  project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name == 'Runner'
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        if config.name == 'Debug'
          config.base_configuration_reference = project.files.find { |file| file.path == 'Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig' }
        elsif config.name == 'Release'
          config.base_configuration_reference = project.files.find { |file| file.path == 'Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.release.xcconfig' }
        elsif config.name == 'Profile'
          config.base_configuration_reference = project.files.find { |file| file.path == 'Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig' }
        end
      end
    end
  end

  # Ensure FlutterMacOS.framework is linked
  runner_target = project.targets.find { |t| t.name == 'Runner' }
  if runner_target
    framework_path = '$(PROJECT_DIR)/Flutter/ephemeral/FlutterMacOS.framework'
    runner_target.frameworks_build_phase.add_file_reference(
      project.frameworks_group.new_file(framework_path)
    )
    runner_target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['OTHER_LDFLAGS'] ||= ['$(inherited)']
      config.build_settings['OTHER_LDFLAGS'] << '-framework FlutterMacOS'
    end
  end

  project.save
end

How can I get rid of those warnings. I have no idea why my project does not contain BaseConfiguration settings in BuildSettings for the Runner target (or any target)
